# Converting random() from cuid to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, browser, cryptoapi

I'm trying to convert this function to Typescript.  It works in the [`cuid` library](https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid/blob/master/lib/getRandomValue.js).

This is what I have so far:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto"

var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;

export function random () {
  return Math.abs(crypto.randomBytes(4)
    .readInt32BE() / lim);
};
```

Typescript says that this method is expecting an argument.  The default value is 0, per the documentation.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-buffer-readint32be-method/

So I assume it's ok to just pass in zero?

Thus it becomes:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto"

var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;

export function random () {
  return Math.abs(crypto.randomBytes(4)
    .readInt32BE(0) / lim);
}
```

Pure Typescript Library:

In case anyone needs it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/cuid

Comment: That would seem logical yes,  I assume the typings are slightly wrong and it's not been marked as optional.

Comment: Thanks - So that would be a bug in Typescript itself right?

Comment: No, that would be a bug in the typings.  http://definitelytyped.org/docs/pg--pg/interfaces/nodebuffer.html#readint32be  And it looks like it's not been marked optional.  You could maybe post a bug report and let them know.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43112